# Graphing function sin2x + cos2x

Tags: trigonometry

I have decided to study calculus and using the materials from MIT OCW. Today I worked on graphing and trigonometry and found this example in their materials:

Given function sin2x + cos2x you need to sketch its curve. They transform it to the form of
A * sin(k * (x-c)) and get in the end

$$
{\sqrt{2}*sin(2*(x - 3π/8))}
$$

But as I see it it is wrong what they get. It should be:
$$
{\sqrt{2}*sin(2*(x + 1π/8))}
$$

As I see it, in order to get this c parameter I need to to this calculation:

$$
c = \frac{-arctan(2/2)}{2} = -\frac{π}{8}
$$

Don't know why they are getting different result. Need some help in order to understand whether I am correct or not. Would appreciate if you share you way of thought regarding solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

You may see the whole example here on page 7 of the document (Example 8) - https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/readings/g_graphng_fnctns.pdf

Comment: The book's answer is wrong. $\sin(0)+\cos(0)=1\ne\sqrt2\sin(-\frac{3\pi}4)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\sin 2x+ \cos 2x$

You can write it as

$\csc \frac{\pi}{4}(\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \sin 2x +\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \cos 2x)$ and equivalently as

$\csc \frac{\pi}{4}(\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \sin 2x +\cos \frac{\pi}{4} \cos 2x)$

$\sqrt 2 (\sin (\frac{\pi}{4}+2x))$

To graph it, draw the curve of $\sin 2x$ by compressing curve of $\sin x$ horizontally and then shifting it $\frac{\pi}{4}$ units towards left and then elongating it $\sqrt 2$ times vertically